# Bind one element's opacity to that of another element

Tags: jquery, transparency, bind, opacity

I've basically got a slider on my page that I'm stuck using and whose source code I cannot manipulate.  But I've got elements that I want to have transition from opaque to transparent and vice/versa in unison with the slides.  How would I bind one element's opacity to that of another, so that the two elements have the same opacity *at all times*, not just when the page is loaded?

EDIT: Here's the code, using a plugin called [jQuery Watch](https://github.com/darcyclarke/jQuery-Watch-Plugin), which apparently is capable of watching for changes in CSS properties, among other things. The plugin itself seems to work because the console registers every time the opacity changes, so that part of the code is okay.  However what *isn't* working is the equivalent opacity change for the target div.  I have verified that the class names are all correct, so that isn't the issue either.

```
$('.slide-0').watch('opacity', function(){
    console.log("Transparency changed!");
    var intentOpacity = $('.slide-0').css('opacity');   
    $('.background-one').css('opacity', intentOpacity); 
});
```

Comment: Can you at least show us the code you have now, and the slider you're using. I would imagine it raises a 'change' event which you can hook to.

Comment: I don't know what slider I'm using; it's integrated into this CMS I'm being forced to use.  But see above.

Comment: Can't you trigger the "change" event of the slider and then change opacity for both elements?
I know it's not the answer you seek but you could use that one as patch.